# Android: Have different merchant and developer accounts

Tags: android, android-pay

I'm developing an android app which will have in-app purchases and ads. My country is not in the list where merchant accounts are supported.

So my question is - is it possible that my partner creates a merchant account in supported country and receives payments for in-app purchases, and I receive payments for ads with my developer account. Or Merchant and developer accounts should be created by the same person?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because 3rd party TOS are off topic here.  Consult a lawyer.

Comment: yeah, lawyers really are aware of setting up google APIs